# Copying Array elements to excel using python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to copy elements of array sequentially to excel .

Here is the code :

```
array = ['A','B','C','D','E']

print len(array)

for i in range(1,len(array)):
sheet2.cell(i,1).value = array[i]
  #print cell
  #sheet2.cell(i,1).value = cell

wb2.save(path2)
```

**Expected :**

> Should sequentially write A,B,C,D,E to the rows in excel

**Actual:**

> Starts writing from B,C,D,E

What am i missing. Something very simple

Answer (score 0):

if you use-> for i in range(1,len(array)):
you'll miss the first element of array because it starts with 1. index
python arrays start with 0 index

use it like -> for i in range(len(array)): or for i in range(0,len(array)):

Comment: First comment i have got it,

Comment: For the second one it gives traceback as - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DATA\PYTHON\Practise\TestCode.py", line 50, in <module>
    sheet2.cell(i,1).value = array[i]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 296, in cell
    raise ValueError("Row or column values must be at least 1")
ValueError: Row or column values must be at least 1

Comment: then you can use it like : sheet2.cell(i+1,1).value = array[i]

Answer (score 0):

In python array starts with zero. This is the correct code:

```
array = ['A','B','C','D','E']

print len(array)

for i in range(0,len(array)):

    sheet2.cell(i+1,1).value = array[i]
      #print cell
      #sheet2.cell(i+1,1).value = cell

wb2.save(path2)
```

Notice that the for loop starts from 0.

Comment: I have tried the first code ofcourse. But it gives a traceback

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DATA\PYTHON\Practise\TestCode.py", line 50, in <module>
    sheet2.cell(i,1).value = array[i]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 296, in cell
    raise ValueError("Row or column values must be at least 1")
ValueError: Row or column values must be at least 1

Comment: DOne now, Thank You !

Comment: If this is the correct answer please accept it. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Python indices start with 0, excel indices apparently with 1. So simply do:

```
array = ['A','B','C','D','E']

print len(array)

for i in range(0,len(array)):
   sheet2.cell(i+1,1).value = array[i]
   print cell
   sheet2.cell(i+1,1).value = cell

wb2.save(path2)
```